# SQL equivalent of C# BigInteger

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

So, I've been using the new `BigInteger` class introduced in **.NET 4** to store **incredibly large** numbers.

Now, I've started thinking about saving these numbers to the database (**SQL Server**). My question is, is this even possible? As far as I know and what I've researched, the SQL data types do not contain a property that corresponds to the behaviour of `BigInteger` (theoretically no min or max).

The closest I've seen is `bigint`, but that has a **minimum** of `-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808)` and a **maximum** of `2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your SQL server's [`DECIMAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) type does not support the precision you need you'll only have the option to store the number as a string or a binary, i.e. in a `VARCHAR`, `TEXT` or `VARBINARY` field.

Comment: Ahhh, that gives much more leway, but `varchar` and `text` are still limited (albeit to 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)).

Comment: +1 - An arbitrarily large number is functionally equivalent to a string anyway.

Comment: A binary(8) or varbinary(8) is sufficient to store a BIGINT (2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)). This is a starting point in determining your max size of binary data type.

Answer (score 5):

You could store the result of calling `yourBigInt.ToByteArray()` in a `VARBINARY(…)`, subsequently retrieving it using the `BigInteger(byte[])` constructor.

The main disadvantage of this approach is that SQL Server would be restricted in its ability to work with the values as numbers (probably limited to comparing them). Then again, that's a foregone conclusion for anything that won't fit into a `bigint`.

Comment: Although slightly higher, `VarBinary` is still limited to 254 encoded bytes

Comment: @mattytommo: Not with `VARBINARY(MAX)`. If you're stuck using a pre-2005 server (and haven't committed suicide yet), you can use `IMAGE` instead.

Comment: Apologies, the limit is 2^31-1 bytes. Although higher, still a limit. Image is also restricted to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes.

Comment: @mattytommo: If your numbers are bigger than 2^(2^34) - 1, then I think you're pretty much on your own.

Comment: Apologies, the question itself wasn't about how large the number was, it was more about a data type with no *theoretical limit*

Comment: @mattytommo: There is no such thing as a storage system with no theoretical limit. There's a finite number of atoms in the universe.

Comment: Not according to quantum physics :). OT: I was hoping for something that would grow in size as it needed to (similar to `varchar(max)` but **without** a finite maximum.

Comment: @mattytommo: Quantum physics isn't a get out of jail free card. The volume of the observable universe is less than 10^200 planck volumes, which places a hard upper limit on the number of bits of information the universe can hold. In any event, more pragmatically, there are limits on everything. NTFS packs it in at 16 EB, for example. More specifically, SQL Server imposes [explicit limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) on every dimension of its storage capacity.

Comment: Quanum physics aside: What about expansion? The universe is constantly expanding, meaning that the space it occupies is **ever-increasing**. Much like what I want my data type to do :).

Comment: @mattytommo: The trouble is that the universe is disappearing at the edges because it's receding faster than light. The observable universe is emptying out, so while its volume may remain the same, the amount matter left in it (to create more hard disks) is decreasing.

Comment: This is fun :D. You are referring to the **observable universe** **not** the **entire universe**. I want a data type that can span the ever-expanding **entire universe**, not be limited by the finite **observable universe** (which is only limited because we can't see further).

Comment: @mattytommo: :-). The entire universe, for all intents and purposes, doesn't exist except as a hologram on the surface of the observable universe, the information carrying capacity of which is (extremely roughly) in the vicinity of 10^130 bits. It's somewhat meaningless to hypothesise a number whose storage occupies a volume so large that it is intrinsically unobservable. Unless someone figures out FTL travel and how to avoid those pesky paradoxes.

Comment: @mattytommo: And let's not forget Graham's number, which would make the most optimistic cosmologist faint.

Comment: I think we've veered off on a *slight* tangent :). My question wasn't really questioning size of numbers, purely if such data type exists that would constantly grow as it needed to (limited only by hardware), similar to how `BigInteger` works in C# :).