# Storing IPv6 Addresses in SQL Server [...with Entity Framework]

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, ipv6, biginteger, entity-framework-6

Trying to work with IPv6 addresses in code, using EF6 for persistence.

Entity Framework 6 does not appear to like .NET `BigIntegers`. In code-first, if you try to Add-Migration with this:

```
Public Property StartBigInt As BigInteger
```

You get the following:

> The property 'StartBigInt' is not a declared property on type 'AssignmentIPV6'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

So code-first isn't happy mapping a `BigInteger` to a SQL Server `bigint` type.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Is there a better way to store IPv6 addresses in SQL Server that will allow relatively quick math on them?

Each row holds an address range (where the Start and Stop addresses are used), so the match just asks whether a given address is within each start & stop column for a row.

Code First in EF6 has gotten me this far very well, but now I'm in a bit of a pickle, and I have a sneaking suspicion that my trying to use `BigInt/BigInteger` to represent a SQL Server `bigint` column might not actually be the best way to work with IPv6 addresses.

What are you guys using out there to work with these 128 bit addresses?

P.S. I have VB Functions to expand & compress IPv6 addresses if they could be of use to anyone. I was planning to expand a compressed address, convert to to `BigInteger`, then persist in SQL Server 2008 R2. Now I'm not so sure I'm doing the right/best thing!

Comment: Have you seen [SQL equivalent of C# BigInteger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246935/sql-equivalent-of-c-sharp-biginteger)?

Comment: I would store it as a string `VARCHAR`

Comment: @AndrewMorton, .NET 4 FINALLY gave us native BigInteger... Up until then, I had to do exactly as you suggest. I just don't know how folks these days are using the EF with IPv6 addresses in SQL Server...

Comment: @DonA, I store the text version (colons, numbers, letters) as varchar, but for math, sorting, etc. I need to know how folks are storing & retrieving IPv6 addresses in the same way that IPv4 addresses can be easily stored as Long(s)...

Comment: _Interesting... Since a moderator has edited my post, I can no longer edit/post updates... (the "edit" ink between the post & comments is inactive)..._ 

What I would have shown is a way I am trying it for now (untested): 

`Property StartBigInt As Byte()`

...and later in the DBContext Class Configuration (column definitions):

`With Me.Property(Function(a) a.StartBigInt)
    .HasColumnType("varbinary")
    .HasMaxLength(16)
    .IsOptional()
End With`

using Code First EF6, so we'll see how it goes... :)

Comment: If your trouble is storing it in that data type then convert it outside of the DB.

Comment: @DonA, is this how you deal with sorting, searching ("SELECT ... WHERE ...", etc.)? What column format do you use?

Comment: The whole reason for being in the database is to do comparative operations... You know, given IPv6 Address A, which db row matches by having StartIPv6 >= A, and StopIPv6 <= A...