# Value too big for long and bigint in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, getter-setter, bigint

Our entire application has been using a long to store large number values.

Like so:

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    public long CardNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This is stored as a `bigint` in Microsoft SQL Server.

Now in order to account for a value larger than a long's max value I'm changing the datatype to a `string` and `nvarchar` in SQL Server (open to a better solution).

We don't seem to be doing much arithmetic with the value already across the application.

But we have code like this:

```cs
var someObj = new SomeClass();
someObj.CardNumber = 1234;
```

So I don't want to have to manually change it to

```cs
var someObj = new SomeClass();
someObj.CardNumber = 1234.ToString();
```

Across the application..

I was thinking of doing something like this..

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private long cardnum;

    public string CardNumber
    {
        get { return cardnum.ToString(); }
        set { cardnum = ConvertToLong(value); }
    }
}
```

but what if I then want to set the card number to a value larger than the long max value....as the convert to long would break in the setter

I'm a bit lost as to what I should do here ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246935/sql-equivalent-of-c-sharp-biginteger

Comment: You don't say, but assuming entity framework, you can setup value conversion. Set your C# model to, say, System.Numerics.BigInteger and convert varchar to that type. Or define a new type. The important part would be implicit value cast from existing int/long to leave existing assignment in code base unchanged.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Why `nvarchar`? presumably it will only contain characters `0-9`? So `varchar` should be fine at half the size

Comment: What does `CardNumber` represent, exactly? You should only use a numeric type if the value is a mathematical number - while things like phone-numbers and credit-card numbers are not actually numbers and so should be stored as strings because they _are_ strings (not least because leading-zeroes are significant).

Comment: @Dai credit card numbers are not really a good example since they should never be stored in clear text.  Regardless your point is spot on.

Comment: @SeanLange I used credit-card numbers as an example specifically because the OP's column is named `CardNumber` (and yes, it really did _rustle my jimmies_ when i saw it and made that assumption, then again, I have seen worse...  and not just here on SO)

Comment: @Dai I know that you would never do anything like that but I couldn't not say something in the hope that somebody else who sees this at least has to think about storing them in clear text.

Comment: @Dai  they are not cc numbers geeze..

Comment: @the1.9gpaProgrammer _"geeze"_ - Remember this is the Internet, where _everyone else_ has **zero context** into your posting, so when we see something like `CardNumber` it's only natural and reasonable to assume it's a reference to a credit-card-number; to further my point: personally I don't have anything in my possession with a "card number" that _isn't_ a credit/debit-card number (otherwise they have different names entirely like  _membership numbers_ or _library card number_): Western society long-ago settled on using "card number" (by itself) as shorthand for payment card account numbers.

Comment: @Dai  I appreciate the concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 28 digits are enough, you could use a [C# decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-7.0). A [SQL decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) has even a precision of 38 digits. [C# long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64?view=net-6.0) has only 18 digits [ulong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64?view=net-6.0) has 19.

An assignment like `someObj.CardNumber = 1234;` will continue to work without changes, as the `int` constant is automatically converted to `decimal`.

For numbers larger than `Int32.MaxValue` you must use a decimal constant with the decimal specifier `m`. `someObj.CardNumber = 1234_5678_9012_3456_7890m;`. You can also use decimal separators. They are not limited to blocks of 3.

Always encrypt sensitive data!

Comment: I should be going with this solution.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you could alter the BIGINT column to be of type NUMERIC.  The maximum integer length available is NUMERIC(38, 0).  One way to store NUMERIC(38, 0) in memory using C# would be to use the (native SQL Server type) [SqlDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal?view=net-6.0) which is implemented as a Struct in System.Data.SqlTypes.

Comment: `numeric` and `decimal` are the same. And you can use `decimal` in C# also, you don't need `SqlDecimal`